# ZendServer 6 enable to open administration Console

Tags: zend-server

I work on MacOS X.8 and since a couple of days each time I try to open administration console, this message display
Unable to connect to

> `http://localhost:10081`

I can access the websites at 10088 just fine.. and all local test sites are working.

Do you know why?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

**There are few possible reasons to have that error:**

- *You turned on your firewall on your mac?* - Just disable and try again if this is the case...
- *Zend admin console's web server process is down/ not starting up.* -  In this case just open your terminal and type `cd /usr/local/zend/bin/` and `sudo ./zendctl.sh restart` and watch for any errors if you get any.

***Good luck.***